# Composite c1 upgrade from 4.0 to 4.2 update 1

Tags: c1-cms

I've just upgraded from 4.0 to 4.2 update 1. Now i got an error as soon as I try to open a page:

System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at CompositePageContentEditor.PageContentEditor.get_SelectedTemplateId() in c:\Development\ValaLocal\website\Composite\controls\FormsControls\FormUiControlTemplates\Customized\PageContentEditor.ascx.cs:line 14
   at CompositePageContentEditor.PageContentEditor.SetUpTextAreas(Boolean flush) in c:\Development\ValaLocal\website\Composite\controls\FormsControls\FormUiControlTemplates\Customized\PageContentEditor.ascx.cs:line 71
   at CompositePageContentEditor.PageContentEditor.InitializeViewState() in c:\Development\ValaLocal\website\Composite\controls\FormsControls\FormUiControlTemplates\Customized\PageContentEditor.ascx.cs:line 60
   at Composite.Plugins.Forms.WebChannel.CustomUiControls.TemplatedPageContentEditorUiControl.InitializeViewState()
   at Composite.Plugins.Forms.WebChannel.UiControlFactories.TemplatedContainerUiControl.InitializeViewState()
   at Composite.Plugins.Forms.WebChannel.UiControlFactories.TemplatedContainerUiControl.InitializeViewState()
   at Composite.Plugins.Forms.WebChannel.UiControlFactories.TemplatedContainerUiControl.InitializeViewState()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
   at Composite_Management_FlowUi.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Development\ValaLocal\website\Composite\content\flow\FlowUi.aspx.cs:line 61
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

any help appreciated!

/Johan

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens if the system cannot find any page templates (I made some changes so in the next version there will be a more appropriate exception message).

You should check the server log for additional details. Could be something wrong with the configuration ("/App_Data/Composite/Composite.config" file) or with the templates itself.